# Format Latex [option]package pairs into \usepackage[option]{package}

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I currently have a set of default LaTeX packages I use frequently formatted as follows:

```
package1
[options]package2
[options]package3
package4
...
```

I would like to be able to convert this to standard LaTeX notation of \usepackage[options]{package} or \usepackage{package} depending on whether the package has additional options. I have successfully created a sed/regex command to convert the lines with options, but it misses the packages without options.

```
echo "[option]package" | sed 's/.*\(\[[^]]*\]\)\(.*\)/\\usepackage\1{\2}/'
>> \usepackage[option]{package}
```

When this is run on a line with just a package, it fails (as I would expect).

```
echo "package" | sed 's/.*\(\[[^]]*\]\)\(.*\)/\\usepackage\1{\2}/'
>> package
```

Is this a regex problem and if so, how should I approach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please verify if this works for you:

```
$ echo -e "[options]package3\npackage4" | sed 's/^\(\[[^]]*\]\)\?\(.*\)/\\usepackage\1{\2}/'
\usepackage[options]{package3}
\usepackage{package4}
```

I replaced `.*` with `^` to match the start of line and added `\?` to make the brackets optional.

Answer (score 0):

This two-step approach seems to be simpler:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'package1' '[options]package2' | sed -e 's/[^]]*$/{&}/' -e 's/^/\\usepackage/'
\usepackage{package1}
\usepackage[options]{package2}
```

- The first step, `s/[^]]*$/{&}/`, puts the project name into curly braces
  by matching the longest possible string of characters other than `]`,
  up to the end of the line.
- The second step, `s/^/\\usepackage/`,
  simply prepends `\usepackage` to the beginning of the line.